# Get grecaptcha in knockout viewmodel asp.net mvc umbraco

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, knockout.js, umbraco, recaptcha

I am trying to use google's recaptcha in my web site(Umbraco). The problem I am facing is that I can not use `grecaptcha` in my viewmodel.

So far, I have included into my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

But when I try to access `grecaptcha` in view model I get

```
cannot resolve symbol grecaptcha
```

error.
So I can't do any of actions related to captcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with `grecapctha.reset()` on view, not viemodel